# How to set up pay to view user posts in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway

I've created a rails app that allows users to sign up and post. I would like to give users the option of charging money for people to view their entire post. In the posts index I would have a list of all the posts with a preview of each one and if someone clicked on a post that required payment to view it then they would be asked for their credit card info etc. I've been researching different payment options and everything I've found seems to be directed towards selling physical products.

Comment: This is pretty broad. There shouldn't be much of a difference between physical products and virtual ones, though.